# 'for' does not loop in boolean method

Tags: java, for-loop

I have this boolean method that is supposed to compare all the characters between the "word" and "inputPlay", and update the int array to value 1 if they match as well as return true.

However, it does not loop and instead stops if it finds a match. What should I do differently?

```
public static boolean updateArray(String word, int[] guesses, String inputPlay) {

    for (int i = 0; i < word.length(); i++) {
        if (inputPlay.charAt(0) == word.charAt(i)) {
            guesses[i] = 1;
        }
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: Do you just want to `return true` *inside* the `if` block?  Some other logic?  Currently this will always return true on the first iteration of the loop.  When do you *want* to return?

Comment: It's because you are returning true in the for loop.

Comment: @MatthewCollins: Then you don't want to return inside the loop.  You want to return after the loop if a match was found.

Comment: Also, `charAt(0)` always gets the first character of `inputPlay` and compares it to the next character of `word` - this should probably be `chartAt(i)`, and be careful if `word` and `inputPlay` are not the same length.

Comment: Please don't make more work for other people by vandalizing your posts. By posting on the Stack Exchange (SE) network, you've granted a non-revocable right, under the [CC BY-SA 3.0 license](//creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/3.0), for SE to distribute that content (i.e. regardless of your future choices). By SE policy, the non-vandalized version of the post is the one which is distributed. Thus, any vandalism will be reverted. If you want to know more about deleting a post please see: [How does deleting work? ...](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5221/271271)

Answer (score 1):

Going off of the assumption that you should return `true` if any of the letters match, you'll need to use a temporary `boolean` that you declare outside the loop:

```
public static boolean updateArray(String word, int[] guesses, String inputPlay) {
    boolean match = false;

    for (int i = 0; i < word.length(); i++) {
        if (inputPlay.charAt(0) == word.charAt(i)) {
            guesses[i] = 1;
            match = true;
        }
    }

    return match;
}
```

Because we set `match` to `true` inside the if-statement, it will still continue iterating and return `true` after the for-loop terminates, assuming any of the letters match. Otherwise, it will return `false`.